# PHP: How to pass Bearer Token in GET/POST Call to Azure API?

Tags: php, azure, active-directory, http-headers, access-token

I've made a call to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token` and received something like this in response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "Directory.Read.All User.Read",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "0",
    "resource": "https://graph.windows.net",
    "access_token": {{really_long_token_1}},
    "refresh_token": {{really_long_token_2}},
    "id_token": {{really_long_token_3}}
}
```

I have a website hosted on HostGator that's trying to access an API I have located on Azure.

What is the correct form of a `GET` call to my API hosted on Azure? Here's what I have so far:

```
$url = 'https://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/api/getValues';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => array(
            'x-ms-version: 2017-06-02',
            'Authorization: Bearer {{really_long_token_1}}'
         ),
        'method' => 'GET'
     )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$var_dump($result);
```

I end up getting `500` Server Errors while making this call.

Answer (score 0):

The `500` is **Internal Error** which indicates the server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

It should not be relative to the authentication/authorization, please check whether there is code can cause this exception. Or you can just replace the code with a very easy code sample without any complex business logic just return the values.